# Camera Button (shutter) icon + iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

Can we change the shutter button icon on a Camera View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can show your own view overlap the default view using these 2 methods. Remember to do `picker.showCameraControls = NO;`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView

@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls
```

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW19)